Pandas data type conversion - two memory metrics with differing answers
Here is a mock example:
import pandas as pd

data = {'category': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print("Memory usage before conversion:")
print(df.memory_usage(deep=True))
print(df.info())

This indicates:

Memory usage before conversion:
Index       128
category    348

As well as the .info() excerpt:

memory usage: 176.0+ bytes

# Convert the 'category' column to categorical data type
df['category'] = df['category'].astype('category')

print("Memory usage after conversion:")
print(df.memory_usage(deep=True))
print(df.info())


Memory usage after conversion:
Index       128
category    288

Great this is what I was expecting to see based on my understanding of converting categorical data. But...
The .info() excerpt reports

memory usage: 266.0 bytes

I was expecting it to acknowledge the decrease that was reported after conversion - but it has not? Why is that?
